# Firestore security rules | Prevent from writing data if a counter is not greater than field stored in DB

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

With Firestore I would like to prevent writing a document if its `counter` value is not higher than the value already stored. `counter` is a field of the document that is increased every new writing. But this must not prevent the creation of the document the first time.

I try to write a security rule for this, I wrote the following rule, but I'm not entirely sure what I've done.

```
      allow create: if request.resource.data.timestamp == request.time              
        && request.auth != null 
        && request.auth.uid == userId; 
      allow write: if request.resource.data.timestamp == request.time 
        && request.resource.data.counter > resource.data.counter
        && request.auth != null 
        && request.auth.uid == userId;
```

Can someone confirm this is the right rules?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reframing your requirement. You now have:

> I would like to prevent writing a document if its counter value is not higher than the value already stored.

While this is common when thinking of data requirements/validation, I find I am more successful at mapping to rules when I frame it as "Writing a document is allowed if...". In your case it reads like:

> Writing a document is allowed if the document doesn't exist yet or if the counter is higher than its current value.

If that's indeed the requirement, it'd translate to:

```
allow write: if (resource == null || request.resource.data.counter > resource.data.counter)
```

You could also use [granular rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations) and split `write` into separate `create` and `update` operations.